# SharePoint workflow: Due date reminders

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, date, reminder

[image]

I have a form that takes 2 dates- a. Assigned due date & b. Adjusted due date.
now, I wish to check that if "adjusted due date" is non empty then use it for reminder mail else use "assigned due date"

Issue: It checks the date only once, whichever is saved first: assigned or adjusted. Any solution?

UPDATED Workflow : [image]

Comment: referring 1st screenshot Are you storing shortdate in variable for making that comparison?

Comment: Date does not start with 1/1/0001.  Its value is ‘1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM’.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use calculated columns for both 'assigned due date' and 'adjusted due date'. These calculated columns stored Yes or No response. If date field is not null then it contains Yes else No. Then in workflow use these calculated columns and based on Yes/No response select a date from these two date fields i.e. assigned and adjusted. Use the selected date in Reminder mail.

Comment: Thanks! This simplified my workflow but issue is still there. I need to send email only once and user can update these dates at any point of time.

Comment: In workflow, you can't get to know whether a field is updated or not when a workflow is called on edit. So you can switch to Event Receiver as there you can get the "Before Property" of a field and its "After Property".